# Deleting *multiple* items from a comma delimted list in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a legacy field which contains a comma delimited list of userID's, I will be replacing this is at some point but for now I just need to maintain it, I have set up a trigger so when a user is added to a group it sticks it in to the list no problem, however when a user is deleted I need a trigger to remove it from the list. I used this bit of code which works fine when you delete just one member at a time, however I need to make it work for multiple deletes in one go, I normally join to the deleted table and boom, I'm away but in this instance it won't work.

Can you give me an idea of the best way to delete multiple userID's from multiple comma delimited strings on a trigger?

Here is the current trigger.

```
DECLARE @MemberID int

SELECT @MemberID = MemberID FROM Deleted 

UPDATE MemberGroups SET MembersList = SUBSTRING(
REVERSE (SUBSTRING (REVERSE (REPLACE(',' + mgs.MembersList + ',', ',' + CAST(@MemberID AS varchar) + ',', ',') ) , 2, 8000) ), 2, 8000)
 FROM MemberGroups mgs
 WHERE ',' + mgs.MembersList + ',' LIKE (',%' + CAST(@MemberID AS Varchar) + '%,')
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would have done in this case:

1. Store the list of IDs to be deleted in a temp table named @todelete.
2. Declare a new list. @newlist varchar(max)
3. Parse the original member list and extract the member ids one by one and put it into @newlist. But while inserting make sure it is not present in @todelete.
4. Replace the content of original member list with the content of @newlist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play a bit with Xml, you can transform the comma-separated list of values into an Xml, apply the modifications, then re-create the list. In my example I transform the string into a well-formed Xml, use the `nodes` and `value` functions to return the rowset, join with `deleted` and keep the remaining member ids, the re-create the string using `FOR XML PATH`. Here is the code:

```
--update the groups if the member list contains more then one item
;WITH results(GroupID, MemberID) AS (
SELECT t.GroupID, t.MemberID FROM (
    SELECT GroupID, t.c.value('text()[1]', 'INT') AS MemberID
    FROM (SELECT GroupID, CONVERT(XML, '<ms><m>' + REPLACE(MemberList, ',', '</m><m>') + '</m></ms>') AS ms FROM MemberGroups) x
    CROSS APPLY x.ms.nodes('//m') AS t(c)
    ) t
LEFT JOIN deleted d ON t.MemberID = d.MemberID
WHERE d.MemberID IS NULL 
) UPDATE mg SET
    MemberList = SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MemberID) FROM results WHERE GroupID = r.GroupID FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 8000)
FROM MemberGroups mg
INNER JOIN results r ON mg.GroupID = r.GroupID

--update the groups if the member list contains one item only
UPDATE mg SET 
    MemberList = NULL
FROM MemberGroups mg
INNER JOIN deleted d ON mg.MemberList = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), d.MemberID)

SELECT * FROM MemberGroups
```

Comment: Thanks, been playing with it, there are a few issues with it, ideally I don't want to be doing all the membergroups every time, as there is another trigger that fires that normalises these membergroups, also if all members get deleted from a membergroup for some reason this procedure doesn't empty the string as expected? I'll keep playing with it, appreciate the response.